# Recomposition Issues only debug build (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

Basically, what is supposed to happen is when you press on the time signature container, it will expand and reveal 4 buttons.[Closed Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSJD5.png) [Opened Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNF6e.png) This works perfectly, what doesn't work is specifically on any debug build the first time you open the container, the text will sometimes update (the numerator and denominator), on the next open however it will update after the first button press and not at all thereafter until you close the container and then recomposition will update the values. With my settings it also seems to only happen on actual builds on my phone although it used to happen on the emulator as well.

I have checked that the parameter is being updated and it is. I put a log.d right above the text for each of the values and they are being updated through the parameters, but the actual graphic isn't being updated.

Again, this only seems to happen on debug builds, but has occasionally happened on the built in emulators on api 28, I have tried both upgrading and downgrading my implementation versions for compose and kotlin among other dependencies.

build.gradle project

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.3.1'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.carsonmiller.metronome"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.carsonmiller.metronome'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.1"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.4.0-alpha02"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.26.4-beta"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.26.4-beta"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.4.0-alpha02'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.5.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.4.0-alpha02"
}
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Metronome"
include ':app'
```

Now my actual code

MainActivity

```
package com.carsonmiller.metronome

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme.colorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.layoutId
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintLayout
import com.carsonmiller.metronome.components.*
import com.carsonmiller.metronome.ui.theme.MetronomeTheme


class ComposeActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val musicSettings = PersistentMusicSettings(this)
            val appSettings = PersistentAppSettings(this)
            MetronomeTheme {
                MainLayout(
                    musicSettings = musicSettings,
                    appSettings = appSettings
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainLayout(musicSettings: PersistentMusicSettings, appSettings: PersistentAppSettings) =
    ConstraintLayout(
        containerConstraints(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = colorScheme.background)
    ) {
        //text for bpm
        BpmTextBody(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .layoutId("bpmText"), bpm = musicSettings.bpm
        )

        //Music staff container
        HeaderBody(
            modifier = Modifier
                .containerModifier(ScreenSettings.headerContainerHeight)
                .layoutId("headerBox"),
            numerator = musicSettings.numerator,
            denominator = musicSettings.denominator,
            appSettings = appSettings,
            musicSettings = musicSettings
        )

        //Button container
        ButtonBody(
            modifier = Modifier
                .containerModifier(ScreenSettings.buttonContainerHeight)
                .layoutId("buttonBox"),
            settings = musicSettings //only pass in settings when state is being changed.
        )

        //settings container
        PagerContainer(modifier = Modifier
            .containerModifier(ScreenSettings.settingsContainerHeight)
            .layoutId("settingsBox"), { Button({appSettings.clearPreferences()}, content = {}) }, { Text("Test2") }, { Text("Test3") })
    }
```

Containers (includes button code)

```
package com.carsonmiller.metronome.components

import com.carsonmiller.metronome.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.horizontalScroll
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.PressInteraction
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonColors
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.composed
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.carsonmiller.metronome.ScreenSettings
import com.google.accompanist.pager.ExperimentalPagerApi
import com.google.accompanist.pager.HorizontalPager
import com.google.accompanist.pager.rememberPagerState
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

/**
 * A container that pages
 */
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun PagerContainer(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, vararg page: @Composable () -> Unit) =
    HorizontalPager(
        modifier = modifier, count = page.size, state = rememberPagerState()
    ) {
        page[it].invoke()
    }

@Composable
fun HorizontalScrollContainer(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, contents: @Composable () -> Unit) =
    Row(modifier = modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())) { contents() }

@Composable
fun MusicButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contents: @Composable () -> Unit,
    isHoldable: Boolean = false,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inversePrimary)
) {
    val interaction = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    Button(
        modifier = modifier,
        onClick = {},
        shape = CircleShape,
        colors = colors,
        interactionSource = interaction
    ) {
        val delayUntilHold = 500L
        val delay = 100L
        /** gets if it is being held */
        LaunchedEffect(interaction) {
            var doButtonAction: Job? = null
            var isHeld = false

            interaction.interactions.collect {
                when (it) {
                    is PressInteraction.Press -> if (isHoldable) {
                        doButtonAction = launch {
                            isHeld = false
                            delay(delayUntilHold)
                            while (true) {
                                isHeld = true
                                onClick()
                                delay(delay)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    is PressInteraction.Release -> {
                        doButtonAction?.cancel()
                        if (!isHeld) onClick()
                    }
                    is PressInteraction.Cancel -> {
                        doButtonAction?.cancel()
                        if (!isHeld) onClick()
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        contents()
    }
}

/**
 * extension factory function for containers
 */
fun Modifier.containerModifier(height: Dp = 0.dp) = composed {
    this
        .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        .height(height)
        .padding(ScreenSettings.containerSidePadding, ScreenSettings.containerHeightPadding)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(ScreenSettings.cornerRounding))
        .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer)
}
```

Constraints for constraint layouts

```
package com.carsonmiller.metronome.components

import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintSet
import com.carsonmiller.metronome.ScreenSettings
import org.json.JSONObject


fun containerConstraints() = ConstraintSet {

    val bpmText = createRefFor("bpmText")
    val header = createRefFor("headerBox")
    val buttonBox = createRefFor("buttonBox")
    val settingsBox = createRefFor("settingsBox")

    constrain(bpmText) {
        end.linkTo(
            parent.end, margin = ScreenSettings.containerSidePadding * 2
        ) //*2 for some contrast
        bottom.linkTo(
            header.top, margin = ScreenSettings.containerMargins / 2 // / 2 to make it closer
        )
    }

    constrain(header) {
        bottom.linkTo(buttonBox.top, margin = ScreenSettings.containerMargins)
        centerHorizontallyTo(parent)
    }

    constrain(buttonBox) {
        centerVerticallyTo(parent, .35f)
        centerHorizontallyTo(parent, .5f)
    }

    constrain(settingsBox) {
        top.linkTo(buttonBox.bottom, margin = ScreenSettings.containerMargins)
        centerHorizontallyTo(parent)
    }
}


fun textConstraints() = ConstraintSet {
    val num = createRefFor("num")
    val bpmText = createRefFor("bpmText")

    constrain(num) {
        start.linkTo(parent.start)
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
    }

    constrain(bpmText) {
        start.linkTo(num.end, margin = 5.dp)
    }
}

fun timeSignatureConstraint(fontSize: Int) = ConstraintSet {
    val topText = createRefFor("topText")
    val bottomText = createRefFor("bottomText")

    constrain(topText) {
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        centerHorizontallyTo(parent, .5f)
    }

    constrain(bottomText) {
        top.linkTo(topText.top, margin = (fontSize / 2).dp) //math to make it sit on top no matter
        centerHorizontallyTo(parent, .5f)              //the font size
    }
}

fun motionTimeSignatureConstraint(expanded: Boolean) : ConstraintSet {
    val verticalPadding = if(expanded) ScreenSettings.innerPadding.value else -100
    val horizontalPadding = if(expanded) ScreenSettings.innerPadding.value else 0
    return ConstraintSet( JSONObject()
        .put("timeSignature", JSONObject()
            .put("centerVertically", "'parent'")
            .put("centerHorizontally", "'parent'")
        )
        .put("topLeft", JSONObject()
            .put("start", listOf("'parent'", "'start'", horizontalPadding))
            .put("top", listOf("'parent'", "'top'", verticalPadding))
        )
        .put("topRight", JSONObject()
            .put("end", listOf("'parent'", "'end'", horizontalPadding))
            .put("top", listOf("'parent'", "'top'", verticalPadding))
        )
        .put("bottomLeft", JSONObject()
            .put("start", listOf("'parent'", "'start'", horizontalPadding))
            .put("bottom", listOf("'parent'", "'bottom'", verticalPadding))
        )
        .put("bottomRight", JSONObject()
            .put("end", listOf("'parent'", "'end'", horizontalPadding))
            .put("bottom", listOf("'parent'", "'bottom'", verticalPadding))
        ).toString(2).replace("\"", ""))
}

fun motionHeaderConstraint(maxWidth: Float, expanded: Boolean): ConstraintSet {
    val timeSignatureContainerWidth = if(expanded) 150 else 80
    val height = ScreenSettings.headerContainerHeight.value
    val padding = ScreenSettings.innerPadding.value
    val maxContainerWidth = maxWidth - ScreenSettings.containerMargins.value * 2 - padding * 5
    return ConstraintSet( JSONObject()
        .put("timeSignatureContainer", JSONObject()
            .put("width", timeSignatureContainerWidth)
            .put("height", height - padding * 2)
            .put("top", listOf("'parent'", "'top'", padding))
            .put("bottom", listOf("'parent'", "'bottom'", padding))
            .put("start", listOf("'parent'", "'start'", padding))
            .put("end", listOf("'noteContainer'", "'start'", padding / 2))
        )
        .put("noteContainer", JSONObject()
            .put("width", maxContainerWidth - timeSignatureContainerWidth)
            .put("height", height - padding * 2)
            .put("top", listOf("'parent'", "'top'", padding))
            .put("bottom", listOf("'parent'", "'bottom'", padding))
            .put("start", listOf("'timeSignatureContainer'", "'end'", padding / 2))
            .put("end", listOf("'parent'", "'end'", padding))
        ).toString(2).replace("\"", ""))
}
```

Contains the code that actually animates and handles the header that's having problems

```
package com.carsonmiller.metronome.components

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.animation.*
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateFloatAsState
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.scale
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorFilter
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.layoutId
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalConfiguration
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ExperimentalMotionApi
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.MotionLayout
import com.carsonmiller.metronome.*
import com.carsonmiller.metronome.R
import com.carsonmiller.metronome.ui.theme.musicFont
import kotlinx.coroutines.async


@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class)
@Composable
fun HeaderBody(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    numerator: Int,
    denominator: Int,
    appSettings: PersistentAppSettings,
    musicSettings: PersistentMusicSettings
) {
    //animation for buttons and container
    val animationProgress by animateFloatAsState(
            // specifying target value on below line.
            targetValue = if (appSettings.timeSignatureExpanded) 1f else 0f,

            // on below line we are specifying
            animationSpec = tween(300)
    )

    val maxWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.toFloat()
    MotionLayout(
        motionHeaderConstraint(maxWidth,false),
        motionHeaderConstraint(maxWidth,true),
        progress = animationProgress,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        TimeSignatureContainer(
            Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(ScreenSettings.cornerRounding))
                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inversePrimary)
                .clickable {
                    appSettings.timeSignatureExpanded = !appSettings.timeSignatureExpanded
                }
                .layoutId("timeSignatureContainer"),
            animationProgress = animationProgress,
            musicSettings = musicSettings,
            numerator = numerator,
            denominator = denominator)

        //Notes and Music Bar Holder
        MusicStaffContainer(
            modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(ScreenSettings.cornerRounding))
            .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inversePrimary)
            .layoutId("noteContainer"))
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class)
@Composable
private fun TimeSignatureContainer(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, animationProgress: Float, musicSettings: PersistentMusicSettings,
    numerator: Int, denominator: Int) {
    //holds and contains logic for time signature
    MotionLayout(
        motionTimeSignatureConstraint(false),
        motionTimeSignatureConstraint(true),
        progress = animationProgress,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {

        TimeSignature(
            modifier = Modifier.layoutId("timeSignature"), numerator, denominator
        )
        val buttonColor =
            ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)

        @Composable
        fun SmallButton(
            layoutId: String, contents: @Composable () -> Unit, onClick: () -> Unit
        ) = MusicButton(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(ScreenSettings.smallButtonContainerHeight)
                .layoutId(layoutId),
            isHoldable = true,
            contents = contents,
            onClick = onClick,
            colors = buttonColor
        )
        SmallButton("topLeft", onClick = { musicSettings.numerator -= 1 }, contents = {})
        SmallButton("topRight", onClick = { musicSettings.numerator += 1 }, contents = {})
        SmallButton("bottomLeft", onClick = { musicSettings.denominator /= 2 }, contents = {})
        SmallButton("bottomRight", onClick = { musicSettings.denominator *= 2 }, contents = {})
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MusicStaffContainer(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) = Box(
    modifier = modifier) {
    //music bar (doesn't actually move)
    MusicBar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .offset(y = 20.dp), 4f //hardcoded values for alignment
    )

    //row
    HorizontalScrollContainer {
        repeat(100) {
            Note(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(55.dp)      //hardcoded values for alignment
                    .offset(y = 12.dp), //hardcoded values for alignment
                note = R.drawable.ic_one_hundred_twenty_eighth_note_both_connected
            )
        }
    }
}

/**
 * ToDo
 */
@Composable
private fun Note(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, note: Int) {
    Image(
        painterResource(id = note),
        modifier = modifier
            .scale(1.004f) //hardcoded values for alignment
            .wrapContentSize(),
        contentDescription = "Note",
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground)
    )
}

/**
 * the music bar (basically just an image with controllable x scale)
 */
@Composable
private fun MusicBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, scale: Float) =
    Image(
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_music_staff),
        modifier = modifier.scale(scale, 1f),
        contentDescription = "Music Staff",
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground)
    )

/**
 * Time signature with controllable numerator and denominator
 */
@Composable
private fun TimeSignature(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, numerator: Int, denominator: Int, fontSize: Int = 70,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground) {
    //makes the font the same size no matter system settings.
    val spFontSize = with(LocalDensity.current) { (fontSize / fontScale).sp }

    //creates the two numbers
    ConstraintLayout(
        timeSignatureConstraint(fontSize), modifier = modifier) {
        TimeSignatureNumber(
            modifier = Modifier.layoutId("topText"),
            value = numerator,
            fontSize = spFontSize,
            color = color
        ) //numerator
        TimeSignatureNumber(
            modifier = Modifier.layoutId("bottomText"),
            value = denominator,
            fontSize = spFontSize,
            color = color
        ) //denominator
    }
}

/**
 * Inner time signature number that is just a wrapper for text
 */
@Composable
private fun TimeSignatureNumber(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, value: Int, fontSize: TextUnit, color: Color) =
    Text(
        text = value.toString(),
        modifier = modifier,
        fontFamily = musicFont,
        fontSize = fontSize,
        color = color
    )
```

Probably where the problem is, but I have no idea. this contains saving logic and mutable state

```
package com.carsonmiller.metronome

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.text.method.TextKeyListener.clear
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

/**
 * abstract class for extending
 */
abstract class PersistentSettings(activity: Activity) {
    protected val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    fun clearPreferences() =
        sharedPref.edit().clear().apply()

    protected fun putInt(string: String, value: Int): Int {
        sharedPref.edit().putInt(string, value).apply()
        return value
    }

    protected fun putBoolean(string: String, value: Boolean): Boolean {
        sharedPref.edit().putBoolean(string, value).apply()
        return value
    }
}

/**
 * holder for settings
 */
class PersistentMusicSettings(activity: Activity) : PersistentSettings(activity) {
    /* strings for sharedPref */
    private val numeratorString = "numerator"
    private val denominatorString = "denominator"
    private val bpmString = "bpm"

    /* backing fields */
    private var _numerator: Int by mutableStateOf(sharedPref.getInt(numeratorString, 4))
    private var _denominator: Int by mutableStateOf(sharedPref.getInt(denominatorString, 4))
    private var _bpm: Int by mutableStateOf(sharedPref.getInt(bpmString, 100))

    var numerator: Int
        get() = _numerator
        set(value) {
            _numerator = when {
                value < 1 -> putInt(numeratorString, 1)
                value > 999 -> putInt(numeratorString, 999)
                else -> putInt(numeratorString, value)
            }
        }

    var denominator: Int
        get() = _denominator
        set(value) {
            _denominator = when {
                value < 1 -> putInt(denominatorString, 1)
                value > 64 -> putInt(denominatorString, 64)
                else -> putInt(denominatorString, value)
            }
        }

    var bpm: Int
        get() = _bpm
        set(value) {
            _bpm = when {
                value < 1 -> putInt(bpmString, 1)
                value > 999 -> putInt(bpmString, 999)
                else -> putInt(bpmString, value)
            }
        }
}

/**
 * holds certain states of the app
 */
class PersistentAppSettings(activity: Activity) : PersistentSettings(activity) {
    /* strings for sharedPref */
    private val timeSignatureExpandedString = "timeSignatureExpanded"

    /* backing fields */
    private var _timeSignatureExpanded: Boolean by mutableStateOf(
        sharedPref.getBoolean(
            timeSignatureExpandedString, false
        )
    )

    var timeSignatureExpanded: Boolean
        get() = _timeSignatureExpanded
        set(value) {
            _timeSignatureExpanded = putBoolean(timeSignatureExpandedString, value)
        }
}

/* Static Screen Setting References for the rest of the app */
class ScreenSettings {
    companion object {
        val cornerRounding: Dp = 10.dp //for rounded shapes

        /* padding */
        val containerSidePadding: Dp = 32.dp
        val containerHeightPadding: Dp = 0.dp
        val innerPadding: Dp = 10.dp //for inside containers

        /* margins */
        val containerMargins: Dp = 20.dp

        /* container heights */
        val headerContainerHeight: Dp = 100.dp
        val buttonContainerHeight: Dp = 80.dp
        val smallButtonContainerHeight: Dp = 25.dp
        val settingsContainerHeight: Dp = 400.dp
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help that you can offer, I'm at a loss for what is wrong.

As stated above, I've tried using Log statements to confirm that new values are being passed to the parameters and they are.

I've also tried messing with the build.gradle files a lot, but no avail there.

EDIT: I thought this only happened on API 28, but when testing the build on other phones (and other APIs) it does the same thing, so it seems the issue is just with the build.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I'm almost certain now it is because of behavior with the two MotionLayouts but I don't exactly know what. What fixes it is rounding the float value that dictates the animation state, ie. instead of

```
val animationProgress by animateFloatAsState(
            // specifying target value on below line.
            targetValue = if (appSettings.timeSignatureExpanded) 1f else 0f,

            // on below line we are specifying
            animationSpec = tween(300)
    )
```

I changed it to

```
val variableFloat = round(
        animateFloatAsState(
            if(appSettings.timeSignatureExpanded) 1f else 0f,
            tween(300),
            .3f
        ).value * 100
    ) / 100
```

I'm not sure why this works, nor do I think it is the best solution. It does seem to work however, so I hope this helps someone down the line.